# Im having trouble with an html structure

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make boxes for those images, not for the entire row.

I've tried putting div tag with a class named caja-img, which contains a specific width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md">
    <div class="contenido">
        <div class="caja-img">
            <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="Autogestion">
        </div>
        <h3 class='text-center'>Facil y seguro!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.caja-img {
    background-color: red;  
 }
```

Instead of coloring all the row, i just want to color the image.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by colour the image?

Comment: do you want image's border?

Comment: i mean, coloring only what "caja-img" contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can style all `<img>` tags in your `<div>`. The CSS would look like this:

```
.caja-img img{
    background-color: red;  
}
```

What this is doing is styling all of the `img` elements inside of `.caja-img`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the element with the class `.caja-img` to `display: inline-block`.

See the code example below:

```css
.caja-img {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md">
  <div class="contenido">
    <div class="caja-img">
      <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="Autogestion">
    </div>
    <h3 class='text-center'>Facil y seguro!</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```